# Error in C# application . System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am not getting why this error is coming i serach in net and not able to get answer .
Technologies using : C#
Visual Studio for debugging the project

**I have a code**

```
 private void InitializeWatcher(string sourceDirectoryPath, string watcherFilter, bool isWatcherIncludeSubdirectories)
        {
            objWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            objWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories =isWatcherIncludeSubdirectories;
            objWatcher.InternalBufferSize = 16384;

            if (Utilities.LogLevel >= Utilities.Informational)
            {
                Utilities.LogMessage("InitializeWatcher: " + sourceDirectoryPath, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine( "sjdakdjasdhas ");
            System.Console.WriteLine( sourceDirectoryPath);
            objWatcher.Path = sourceDirectoryPath;
            objWatcher.Filter = watcherFilter;
            objWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(objWatcher_FileSystemEvent);
            objWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(objWatcher_FileSystemEvent);
            objWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(objWatcher_FileSystemEvent);
            objWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(objWatcher_Error);
            try
            {
                objWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
            catch (Exception camp)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("camp -->");
                System.Console.WriteLine(camp);
            }
            FileSystemEventArgs objFileSystemEventArgs = new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed, objWatcher.Path+"\\","\\");
            objWatcher_FileSystemEvent(objWatcher, objFileSystemEventArgs);
            watcherQueue.Add(objWatcher);
        }
```

**When have run the code and it gives error like this.**

```
sjdakdjasdhas 
\\10.197.132.58\share1
camp -->
System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at xyzprojectpath.FileSystemWatcherWrapper.InitializeWatcher(String sourceDirectoryPath, String watcherFilter, Boolean isWatcherIncludeSubdirectories) in xyzpath\FileSystemWatcherWrapper.cs:line 123
```

Any help? I don't know about .NET to much . If needed more code please let me know .

Error is coming on this line

**objWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;**

Comment: A quick search on `FileSystemWatcher` and `UNC` indicates that permissions are frequently an issue for this.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough permissions for this?

Comment: I have run my visual stdio by administration right ? I think i have give permission . How can i check i have permission for this task or not .

Comment: You miss the trailing path delimiter for the root of the share. **\\server\share** is only the share as **C:** is only the local drive. Use \\server\share\ or C:\ for the root path.